# How to prove the set of all permutations of a finite number of objects forms a group - differently?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Consider the set of all permutation vectors of n distinct numbers, say 1,2,3, ....n.  Define + operation on this set c= a+b for every a and b from the set as c(i) = a(b(i)).  I have checked with several examples of n like 4, 8, 12 etc.  I did not find any counterexample for saying it is not a group.  Basically we have to prove that it is closed, associative and has identity element and that every element has inverse element.  Closed, I am convinced, though I did not prove formally.  Similarly, for identity element and inverse element.  How to prove associativity.  I saw some proof saying some swaps/exchanges etc but I did not fully understand.  Is there a way of proving associativity for these elements as such without using the concept of swaps or exchanges? I could check that it is not abelian with some examples.

Comment: The permutations are just the bijective mappings from $\{1, \ldots n\}$ to $\{1, \ldots n\}$ while the group operation is the composition of functions. Where exactly is now your problem with showing that it is closed and associative? And the identity and inverses are not that hard too.

Comment: It's a basic fact of mathematics that the composition of maps is associative: $$\bigl(f\circ(g\circ h)\bigr)(x)=f\bigl((g\circ h)(x)\bigr)=f\bigl(g(h(x))\bigr)=\ldots$$

Comment: The way I have defined the + operation on the set i.e. c(i) = a(b(i)), I think it is more appropriate to think it as a binary operation than a bijection.